# In Java, why does untyped call of constructor of parameterised type provoke compiler warning?

Tags: java, generics

In Java, why does an untyped invocation of a constructor of parameterised type provoke a compiler warning?  Why is it okay to do similar thing with a static method?  For example:

```
class Test<T> {

    Test() {}

    static <T> Test<T> create() {
        return new Test<T>();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test<String> warning = new Test();  // compiler warning - why?
        Test<String> okay = Test.create(); // no warning here - why?
        Test<String> okay2 = Test.<String>create(); // why doesn't it need this?
    }

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you assign an untyped instance to a typed variable. Your three cases:

1. Because `new Test<String>()` would be correct.
2. Because Java supports automatic type inference based on the return type, i.e. it can imply the missign generic argument here, and *inside* the method, you've made the generic type explict, by using `new Test<T>()` (instead of just `new Test()`).
3. Because of 2. ;-)

Comment: I have a question related to this:

As to point 1), is that because Task() is equivalent to Task<Object>(), which would imply the risk of unsafe downcasts (you could e.g. add a Number to the Task)?

Comment: @Matthias: no, not entirely – but for all practical intents and purposes (except the generated warnings), it is. `Task<Object>` is still explicitly typed, while the above isn’t. At runtime, it all resolves to `Object` anyway because of type erasure.

Answer (score 1):

Java does type inference on methods (which is why line 2 works and line 3 is not necessary), but not on constructors (which is why line 1 gives a warning).

It would be nice if Java did type inference on constructors too, but as of Java 6 it does not.